# STATIC_ROOT setting in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am learning Django and have built a sample Django app. It works fine on my computer, but I am having trouble deploying it to Heroku. 
My root directory has the following structure:
[image: First screen]

[image: Second screen]

My setttings.py file has the following settings for static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

The full settings.py file is following:

```
    """
Django settings for firstdjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'j8s(6fw61+cx_o=g!9a(vs!wbj0&f!7u_lw$(eap5d4li@!b4('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'inventory',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'firstdjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['firstdjango/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'firstdjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age = 500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
# ]
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

When I try to deploy to Heroku, I get the following error message:

ImproperlyConfigured:You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Comment: @user1787331 That's okay, but I would like to know the right way to set up static files in Django and what I am missing.

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: Please show the rest of your settings file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have included complete settings.py file in the question now.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the recommended settings for static root for a django -> heroku project

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/    

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]
```

I would recommend just using this https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template as a starting point and import your apps into that project. Due to the fact (as of now) that Heroku recommends using the following packages

```
Gunicorn 
WhiteNoise
dj-database-url
```

The git project will provide you with "Production-ready configuration for Static Files, Database Settings, Gunicorn, etc." In other words, it will give you the correct configuration to deploy Django to Heroku.